# Angular-Material, How to change color of selected mat-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

how can I change the color of this text 2020 "selected by mat-option"
Here's the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlKnD.png) and my code is

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 100px;">
<mat-label>Year</mat-label>
<mat-select formControlName="year">
    <mat-option [value]="2020">
       2020
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="2021">
        2021
    </mat-option> 
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS-

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-value
{    
      color: green!important;  
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?